# Correct summary assignment

Tags: r, output, variable-assignment, stargazer

Let's consider stargazer package :

```
library(stargazer)
```

I want to create summary with respect to that package and assign it :

```
model <- lm(rnorm(100)~runif(100))
model_summary <- stargazer(model, type='text')
```

But the problem is that :

```
stargazer(model, type='text')
```

gives :

```
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                            rnorm(100)         
-----------------------------------------------
runif(100)                     0.522           
                              (0.388)          
                                               
Constant                      -0.246           
                              (0.223)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    100            
R2                             0.018           
Adjusted R2                    0.008           
Residual Std. Error       1.124 (df = 98)      
F Statistic             1.809 (df = 1; 98)     
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

And `model_summary` gives :

```
[1] ""                                                "==============================================="
 [3] "                        Dependent variable:    " "                    ---------------------------"
 [5] "                            rnorm(100)         " "-----------------------------------------------"
 [7] "runif(100)                     0.522           " "                              (0.388)          "
 [9] "                                               " "Constant                      -0.246           "
[11] "                              (0.223)          " "                                               "
[13] "-----------------------------------------------" "Observations                    100            "
[15] "R2                             0.018           " "Adjusted R2                    0.008           "
[17] "Residual Std. Error       1.124 (df = 98)      " "F Statistic             1.809 (df = 1; 98)     "
[19] "===============================================" "Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01"
```

How come they give different outputs ? How can I make them to give same result ?

**EDIT**

What finally I want to have is a list that includes `model_summary`.

i.e.

```
output <- list()
output['summary'] <- model_summary 
output$summary 
===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                            rnorm(100)         
-----------------------------------------------
runif(100)                     0.522           
                              (0.388)          
                                               
Constant                      -0.246           
                              (0.223)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    100            
R2                             0.018           
Adjusted R2                    0.008           
Residual Std. Error       1.124 (df = 98)      
F Statistic             1.809 (df = 1; 98)     
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Answer (score 2):

You can regenerate the output in the same format using :

```
cat(paste0(model_summary, collapse = '\n'))

#===============================================
#                        Dependent variable:    
#                    ---------------------------
#                            rnorm(100)         
#-----------------------------------------------
#runif(100)                    -0.671*          
#                              (0.365)          
#                                               
#Constant                      0.468**          
#                              (0.223)          
#                                               
#-----------------------------------------------
#Observations                    100            
#R2                             0.033           
#Adjusted R2                    0.023           
#Residual Std. Error       1.122 (df = 98)      
#F Statistic             3.375* (df = 1; 98)    
#===============================================
#Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: Hmm, I see your solution, but it doesn't exactly solve my problem. 

Doing 

model_summary <- cat(paste0(model_summary, collapse = '\n')) 

and after assignment using

'model_summary' I get NULL in output

Comment: I mean is there any possibility that I can assign this summary to variable and refer to it ?

Comment: @John then do not use `cat`, and you can refer like: `cat(model_summary)`.

Comment: @John You can not assign print output to a variable.

Comment: @John `paste0(model_summary, collapse = '\n')` is exactly what you want. `cat` is just used for printing and it returns `NULL`. Where exactly are you planning to use it?

Comment: Hey Ronak, I updated my question what exactly I would prefer  ;))

Comment: I am still curious to know *why* you want that. Anyway, you can store it as `output <- list();output[['summary']] <- paste0(model_summary, collapse = '\n')` and then while printing use `cat(output$summary)`

Comment: Okay I see, so we cannot omit 'cat' before output$summary ?

Comment: i.e. is there any possiblity to have same output as cat(output$summary) only using output$summary

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid hash given by @Ronak Shah

```
library(magrittr)
paste(model_summary, collapse = "\n") %>% cat 

===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                             rnorm(10)         
-----------------------------------------------
Constant                      -0.373           
                              (0.294)          
                                               
-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    10             
R2                             0.000           
Adjusted R2                    0.000           
Residual Std. Error       0.931 (df = 9)       
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: I manually added hash in the output. Your answer is no different than mine.

Comment: @RonakShah I thought it was part of your output. I just realised both of us have given same code.